# "Visible Section not found" at backend login in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, adminform, magento2.2.3, admin-controller

When I switch the store to a specific domain `https://`  `example.com` (secure & unsecure), I get the error "Visible Section not found" when trying to log into the backend.

The funny thing: as soon as I change the url to something else say `www.example.com` the error disappears and I am able to login fine.

I was testing a lot (Enviroment Varibles, Cache flush, recompiling)

Can anybody explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the "Visible Section not found" error means that the session didn't work in any way.

I had the trouble now twice. One time it was a `.example.com` set as the cookie domain while the domain in use was ´example.com´ the second time it was due to a not available compression format within the redis config.

Comment: Solution: Delete cookies

Answer (score 2):

This error is because of Admin session time is over.

To avoid this error You can increase the session time of Admin user. With the following step...

> **Stores > Configuration > Advance > Admin > security**

Change the value of **"Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)"** field

Comment: I'm afraid, this is not it. The value you're referring to is @ 2700.

Comment: Also, this wouldn't explain that, upon a url change everything is working.

Answer (score 2):

Just clear browser cookies and all done.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

After changing url: please logout and run these commands from SSH as follows:

```
1. php bin/magento cache:flush
2. php bin/magento indexer:reindex

3. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
4. php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
5. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

then Login to admin and check..

Comment: Done that a LOT. It doesn't help. I can change to ANY domain but the one specific.  www. is working .domain is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Community Ver. 2.2.3

Struggled a lot.
I tried to remove caches, pub/static/ files, and sessions.

But the solution was very easy.
Go to magento_root/app/etc/ then open file env.php

Change below **frontName** xxxxxx with what you want

**return array (
  'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'xxxxxx',
  ),**

It worked.